# Removing redundant code

Tags: apex

I am noticing there is a lot of redundant code in the Apex project I am working on.
Is there any special way / tool or whatever to figure out what code never gets called in your code base?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1697/static-code-analysis.  Perhaps some of the static code analysis tools can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there are no refactoring tools as such, though depending on how confident you are about the functional coverage of your Apex tests. You can utilise the code coverage as measure for this, you can also view in a colour coded way, code covered and that not.

Do make sure if your building a managed package, that before you release you scan at least for classes that are marked as 'global' as these can only be cleaned out and not removed once released.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it calls apex test class. After running a test class you can check the code coverage and see what code is really in use.

[image]

Comment: This just shows which code has test code right. You may have code + test code, but never really use that code for anything functional.

Comment: But then you know that you have a test code that is never used. My example is for subconsciously unused code.