# Salesforce org health check

Tags: org

Is there any out of the box feature available in salesforce or by any third party app that can help me in providing my salesforce org health report.
Health means to say any issues in org due to any implementations, governor limits, long running queries or anything.
I need something in dashboard or report form.

Comment: Use checkmarx scan here is the link to http://lp.checkmarx.com/sfdc-vip/

Comment: Try the Tquila Org Doctor: [link](http://www.tquila.com/tquila-org-doctor)

Comment: It's a near duplicate in many ways. You should look at the linked tools anyway. [Apex static code analysis](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1697/2995)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is one provided by Salesforce.com Trust.  I was lucky enough to come across this during [**my experience in Dreamforce'15**](https://sfdcfanboy.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/dreamforce-wrap-up-2015/).  The tool is called **Force.com Security Source Scanner**

This a cloud based source code analysis tool built directly into our Force.com offering.  Once you connect your instance to this, it scans all the code and comes up with the apex coding and design issues.

The results will be emailed and takes time (up to a day depending on the size of the org) for processing.  The email document will also include tips on how to resolve those issues with the org.

I was able to scan my personal developer account there and got the results in an hour.  The staff was kind enough to explain all the flaws in my org and the ways to fix it.

This is a Self Assessment tool to start off
https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/assessment

Here you can login with your org
https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner

But before that I recommend you to read this help document from them.  Because you can choose what kind of analysis to be done in your org. For example **Security Profile** or **Quality Profile** or **Salesforce1 Security Profile**

https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scannerhelp

Hope this helps!