# Is there an Apex Linter out there?

Tags: apex, code

I haven't seen an Apex linter and was wondering if anyone knew of one or had repurposed a Java linter?  I'm so used to having this available when writing JavaScript or Ruby, it would be awesome to see the same reminders while coding Apex.

Comment: You might consider looking into [PMD](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/10944/2995). It does more than linting, but I think it can be used for that to some extent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's [PMD Apex](https://pmd.github.io/), which has a bunch of linting, plus various rules for SOQL inside loops, etc. That's the only one I'm aware of today.

Answer (score 2):

sorry, this is an old post. But consider Clayton.io. It attaches to your source control repository (assuming you have one). I think it works on bitbucket and github at least.

I've used it for a month or two and it's great
https://www.clayton.io/

Cheers
Scott

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working with this one and it seems promising:

https://github.com/renatoliveira/apexlint

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apex PMD in:

- Visual Studio Code: [Apex PMD VsCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-pmd)
- CI/CD: [Mega-linter](https://nvuillam.github.io/mega-linter/), for GitHub Actions, Circle CI, Jenkins and Azure, aggregates 70 linters including [sfdx-scanner](https://nvuillam.github.io/mega-linter/descriptors/salesforce_sfdx_scanner/) ([Apex PMD](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-pmd), eslint for Aura and LWC)